# How to redirect user based on application roaming settings with WinJS.Navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation, microsoft-metro, winjs

i am developing a windows 8 html/java-script metro app.
When the user first start the application, a welcomepage with a textbox where the user can enter his/her user name will show up. When the user has pressed the button, the user name is saved and a redirect take place. This code works fine...

```
var appData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
button.onclick = function (e) {
    var input = document.querySelector(".welcome #userName").value;
    if(input != null && input != "") {
         appData.roamingSettings.values["userName"] = input;
          WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/items/items.html");
    }
}
```

The second time the user enter the application, i want a redirect from the start-page to the content page to accrue, without any action from the user... So i take a look at the roamingSettings and if it contains the key "userName", i try to make the same WinJS call as in the buttons onclick function.

```
if (appData.roamingSettings.values.hasKey("userName")) {
   WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/items/items.html");
}
```

The problem is, that this time, no redirect take place and the application fails..(the roamingSettings contains the correct information so its the redirect that's the problem).The code is placed inside the ready function.

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/welcome/welcome.html", {
   ready: function (element, options) {
})();
```

So my question is, what is the correct way to preform a conditional redirect from one page to another with WinJS.Navigation and whats the problem with my code?

Comment: Have you tried placing your conditional redirect inside you default.js file instead? In the activated event handler? This should give you a better user experience anyways as it won't cause the user to wait for the welcome page to be ready, then be redirected to the items page, also causing there to be a back button on the items page to the welcome page.

Comment: its a much better solution to place it in the default.js, thanks for a useful comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing the navigation in the default.js (as suggested by @Gotdibbs) should work. code in activated handler should look something like this towards end of the function.

```
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
    // if app was suspended while on a page, go there
    // else ...
    if (nav.location) {
        nav.history.current.initialPlaceholder = true;
        return nav.navigate(nav.location, nav.state);
    }
    else if (appData.roamingSettings.values.hasKey("userName")) {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/items/items.html");
    }
    else {
        return nav.navigate(Application.navigator.home);
    }
}));
```